# same eloquent query with different query scope

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a user mode

```
class User extends Model {
 public function scopeNeutral($query)
 {
   return $query->where('score', 0);
 }

 public function scopePositive($query)
 {
    return $query->where('score', '>', 8);
 }

 public function scopeNegative($query)
 {
  return $query->whereBetween('score', [1, 3]);
 } 

 public function team()
 {
      return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
 }
}
```

I need to get all positive, negative and neutral users of a team in the controller,

e.g

```
$users = $team->users();

$positive = $users->positive();
$negative = $users->negative();
$neutral  = $users->neutral();
```

What this is doing is appending a where clauses with every use of query, I need a separate query for each usage.

Comment: You have some typos and the formulation of the sentences is not clearly enough stating your problem. Also you could work on the formatting of the post.

Comment: Did it for him briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following

```
$positive = $team->users()->positive()->get(); 
$negative = $team->users()->negative()->get();
```

The issue you are facing is the query object `$users` is just adding a where clause each time you call a method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is due to the fact that scope methods you are using are in fact changing the internal state of the $users object.

You could, for example, clone the original $users object, like that:

```
$users = $team->users();

$positive = clone $users; $positive = $positive->positive();

$negative = clone $users; $negative = $negative->negative();

$neutral = clone $users; $negative->neutral();
```

Sorry for really poor naming here, I hope you get the idea.

There is also a `newQuery` method which I think should work, but above solution, I am sure will work.

[Here you can read about cloning objects in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Comment: I have done the same, I need a simpler way to do it, code looks messy

Comment: Check the another Answer by @Ken 

something like 

    $positive = $team->users()->positive();


    $negative = $team->users()->negative(); 


    $neutral  = $team->users()->neutral();